# Moving laravel vendor to server

Tags: php, laravel, directory, public, vendor

I'm transferring laravel to the server for the first time.
I have folder public_html, which the server points.

Folder vendor etc. should I move to public_html or parent folder and folder (which was created by laravel) 'public' rename to 'public_html'?

Comment: Do you want to upload this project into the main domain?

Comment: Yes, I want to upload this project into the main domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the steps carefully

1. Create a folder inside `/public_html` i.e- `/public_html/myproject`
2. upload your project and extract, then move the whole project inside `public_html/myproject/`
3. Now go to the public folder and which is inside `public_html/myproject/public`
4. Get all files from `public_html/myproject/public/` and move to `/public_html/`
5. Now open `index.php` file which is inside `/public_html/index.php` and edit this file
6. Find out:

   `require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';`

   `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';`

Replace with

```
require __DIR__.'/myproject/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/myproject/bootstrap/app.php';
```

7. Now you're ready to go. Just setup your database carefully!!